# Is there an easy way to change the ActioMode "Cancel" button text?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am using ActionMode to show a list of context functions for a ListView.   I have the ActionMode bar working but by default it puts a "Cancel" button on the upper left side.   To me this is a little misleading to users. I don't want them to think this button will undo the action.

Is there an easy way change this buttons text to something like "Done" or "Finish"?  I looked through the source and found that this seems to be tied to a theme style.  I was hoping not to have to modify the theme but can if needed.

I am targeting 3.2 or later.

Comment: I just looked at this using the emulator.  On the emulator it renders as a green button with the text "Done" so I'm guessing this is really just a theme issue.  I was testing on a Galaxy Tab 10.1 both the emulator and the GT are running 3.2 but I guess there are some differences in the Holo theme.   I'm still hoping there is an easy solution so I can be achieve some consistency on different devices.

Comment: I am reasonably certain that this can only be adjusted using a theme.

Comment: Further research seems to confirm this CommonsWare.  Thank you for the feedback. 

P.S.  How do I mark this as correct answer?  Or, should I just answer my own question even though its not really an answer?  - Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reasonably certain that this can only be adjusted using a theme. Certainly, there are no methods on `ActionBar` or `ActionMode` for making this change. One *hopes* that it is at least possible via a theme -- I did not try sifting through all the theme stuff to find the actual value to change, and so it's possible that it simply cannot be changed at all (which would suck).

Comment: I'm sorry but which was it...? Cannot be done or can be changed through the theme? I'm hoping the latter. Why doesn't Samsung realize the "Cancel" is wrong usage in this instance. Terrible. I'm having the same issue.